# Mouseenter/Mouseover events do not fire if CSS3 translate/transform is used to change element position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover, mousewheel

I am translating ( via jQuery / CSS3 ) a `#wrapper` div, by updating `Y` axis.

I've attached `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` events to child elements of `#wrapper`.

When `#wrapper` translates, its child comes under mouse one by one ( even if mouse does not move ). And this does not fire the `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` events.

However, events are fired when element has scrollbar and scrolled by mousewheel ( instead of translating ).

Is this a default behavior ? If yes, any workaround ?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CnanH/)**

Try scrolling with mousewheel, without moving mouse. I expect to change the background of `.block` to `red` color, but it's not happening.

Comment: Most events are triggered only by user actions, not by actions of the browser itself. E.g. `change` is only triggered when the user modifies an input, not when a script assigns to `element.value`. So it makes sense that `mouseenter` events would only be triggered when the user moves the mouse into the element, not when the element moves under the mouse.

Comment: You never use `scrolltop()`, `offset()` or `scroll()`, I could not find it in code, but it is cumbersome to search through the code in JSFIDDLE, have to paste into editor. ;)

Comment: @Barmar, but it does fire in case of default scroll. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CnanH/3/)

Comment: well, @Jashwant, scrolling **is** a user action, so Barmar still has a point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Example**:

`document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`

**Definition from [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.elementFromPoint)**:

> Returns the element from the document whose elementFromPoint method is
>   being called which is the topmost element which lies under the given
>   point.  To get an element, specify the point via coordinates, in CSS
>   pixels, relative to the upper-left-most point in the window or frame
>   containing the document.

**Browser support from [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20)**:

- Internet Explorer 5.5+
- Mozilla FireFox 3+
- Safari Win 5+
- Google Chrome 4+
- Opera 10.53+

**Solution 1** [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/CnanH/1/)*:

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
$(containerElement).mousewheel(function(event) {
    $(elementClass).trigger('mouseleave');
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(currentMousePos.x, currentMousePos.y);
    $(element).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

<sup>* there are some bugs, but you get the idea</sup>

**Solution 2**:

Use `debounce` from [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) libraries, to reduce load on client.

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
var debounced = _.debounce(function () {
    $(elementClass).trigger('mouseleave');
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(currentMousePos.x, currentMousePos.y);
    $(element).trigger('mouseenter');
}, 150);
$(containerElement).mousewheel(function (event) {
    debounced();
});
```

Comment: Wow, great thinking, but I don't think it's cross browser.

Comment: Well it's IE9+ http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/06/more_ie9_goodne.html

Comment: Yes, I checked the quirksmode too and hence replied :(

Comment: @Jashwant so what is the browser support that you're looking for?

Comment: @Jashwant What if you capture the last position of you're mouse and then on each scroll iterate over all your elements and calculate their relative position on screen, and then if an element is in range highlight it? That is basically what `elementFromPoint` does in its essence, why don't you try to do it manually?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my last way. On each scroll event, check the 'y' index and then compare that with the offset of `.block`

Comment: I would use lodash or underscore `debounce` function with time delay `100ms - 200ms` to not overwhelm the browser with calculations.